# What is $(C, D, \delta, \gamma)$ and $(C, \delta; D, \gamma)$ Desarguesian?

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, projective-geometry, incidence-geometry, automorphisms

A projective plane is $(C, \gamma)$-Desarguesian if for any 2 triangles $A_1 B_1 C_1, A_2 B_2 C_2$ in perspective from $C$ (which means $C \in A_1 A_2, B_1 B_2, C_1 C_2$) such that $A_1 B_1 \cap A_2 B_2, A_1 C_1 \cap A_2 C_2$ lie on $\gamma,$ so does $B_1 C_1 \cap B_2 C_2.$

Zickert's *Projektive Ebenen* (1955) defines $(C, D, \delta, \gamma)$-Desarguian on page 76 in the following way:

> Macht man nun eine der Geraden $\alpha_{ik}$ oder $\beta_{ik}$ sowie einen der Punkte $A_i, A_k$ bzw. $B_i, B_k$ zu Festelementen mit den Werten $\delta,D,$ so entsteht nach dem eben Bewiesenen nur eine Spezialisierung, die als Desarguesscher $(C, D, \delta, \gamma)$-Satz bezeiehnet werden soll.

I translated this as such:

> If you fix one of the lines $\alpha_{ik}$ or $\beta_{ik}$ and one of the Points $A_i, A_k$ or $B_i, B_k$ as $​​\delta,D$ respectively, according to what has just been proved, only one specialization arises, which should be called Desargues' $(C, D, \delta, \gamma)$ theorem

$\alpha_{ik}, \beta_{ik}$ is the line $A_i A_k, B_i B_k$ respectively. Here is the diagram:

[image]

As I see it, a projective plane is $(C, D, \delta, \gamma)$-Desarguian if for any 2 triangles $A_1 B_1 C_1, A_2 B_2 C_2$ in perspective from $C$ such that $A_1 B_1 \cap A_2 B_2, A_1 C_1 \cap A_2 C_2$ lie on $\gamma$ and $A_1 = D, A_1 A_k = \delta,$ we have $B_1 C_1 \cap B_2 C_2 \in \gamma.$ In other words, only $(C, \gamma)$ Desarguesian for a special case of the configuration determined by fixing one side of one of the triangles. Is this correct?

Now the author proceeds to define $(C, \delta; D, \gamma)$ Desarguian, which I don't get.

> Soll nun ein solches Paar zusammengehoriger Variabler zu Festelementen mit den Werten $C',\gamma'$ gemacht werden, so ergibt das nach S. 74/75 also nur zwei verschiedene Spezialisierungen, wenn wieder die Wahl von $C_{23}$ als Festelement ausscheidet. Die folgende Verabredung macht es jedoch moglich, fUr beide nur eine einzige Bezeichnung zu verwenden. Aus der Voraussetzung des $(C,\gamma)$-Satzes folgt namlich $A_1 \not\in \gamma, C \not\in \beta_{23}, C_{12} \in \gamma, C \in \gamma_3.$ Es erscheint daher sinnvoll, von $C',\gamma'$ entweder $$(5) \ \ C \not\in \gamma', C' \not\in \gamma$$ oder $$(6) \ \ C \in \gamma', C' \in \gamma$$ zu verlangen. Je nachdem, ob (5) oder (6) erfiillt ist, soll dann unter dem Desarguesschen $(C,\gamma; C',\gamma')$-Satz die Spezialisierung mit $C' = A_1, \gamma' = \beta_{23}$ oder die mit $C' = C_{12}, \gamma' = \gamma_3$ verstanden werden.

I translated this as follows:

> If I now fix such a pair of related variables to $C',\gamma',$ then according to p.74-5 this results in only two different specializations, if again the choice of $C_{23}$ is fixed. However, the following agreement makes it possible for both to use a single designation. From the assumption of the $(C,\gamma)$-theorem it follows that $A_1 \not\in \gamma, C \not\in \beta_{23}, C_{12} \in \gamma, C \in \gamma_3.$ It therefore makes sense to require from $C', \gamma'$ that either $$(5) \ \ C \not\in \gamma', C' \not\in \gamma$$ oder $$(6) \ \ C \in \gamma', C' \in \gamma.$$ Depending on whether (5) or (6) is fulfilled, under the Desargues $(C, \gamma; C', \gamma')$ theorem the specialization can be understood with $C' = A_1, \gamma' = \beta_{23}$ or with $C' = C_{12}, \gamma' = \gamma_3.$

This is the 1st time in the book the notation $(C, \delta; D, \gamma)$ is used, and yet the phrasing makes it seem like it's already been defined. Perhaps I didn't translate correctly, but I don't see how this is a definition.

Comment: Pedantic comment but I think "Desarguesian" is the more common adjective form in English...

Comment: @SamHopkins You're right, fixed

Comment: It irritates me that the s is silent in Desargues, but (I suppose) not in Desarguesian. I would prefer using Desargues as the adjective, for that reason, and because Desarguesian is long and sounds ugly. While it was once standard practice in English to make adjectives by adding adjectival endings, that is rare for adjectives minted since the early 20th century (Cartan subalgebra, Gauss-Manin connection, ...), so there is really no need to put ian on the end.